# Can I pull data from server to client with Iperf?

Tags: networking, performance, iperf

To test bandwidth, I just can push data from client to server with iperf. But can i pull data from server to client ? that is like webserver, the client request data, then server give data to client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iperf is capable of bidrectional tests, either simultaneously with "-d" or sequentially with "-r". Using "-r" will test bandwidth from client to server first, then server to client afterwards which is what you're after, I believe.

Comment: thanks! But i just need test server to the client because of PPTP, you know, one client which connects PPTP(virtual ip is 172.17.0.10) can find other pc without connecting pptp(192.168.1.21), but other pc without connecting pptp can not find the virtual ip. my purpose is testing the PPTP traffic.

Comment: I want to test the bandwidth  from one ethnet ip to one pptp virtual ip, maybe i need to program to deal with it myself

Comment: So basically you have a PPTP end-point and a real network "behind" it with servers and you want to test the bandwidth from a server which is on the real network to the clients which connect over PPTP?

Comment: right! is there any good method to do this ?

Comment: @cense, can i skip the first step with the "-r" ?

Comment: @why, Not exactly skipping the test, but you can simply run the iperf "server" on the client system connecting via PPTP and the iperf "client" on the actual server that is sitting on the real network, behind the PPTP end-point. This way you'll be testing bandwidth from the server on the real network to the client connecting via PPTP.